# Getting og information when there is redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, facebook-opengraph, reddit

I am trying to get the og information of this URL:

`https://www.reddit.com/r/DunderMifflin/comments/6x62mz/just_michael_pouring_sugar_into_a_diet_coke/`

I use [open-graph-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper). But the problem is that it first loads an empty page without og information, then a second page is loaded which has the correct og information. The open-graph-scraper only loads og information from the first page. Is there any way that I can get the correct info?

Comment: The open-graph-scraper library uses the request library underneath, which follows redirects automatically (at least in theory). Have you tried increasing the timeout?

Comment: ```var ogs = require('open-graph-scraper');
var options = {'url': 'https://www.reddit.com/r/DunderMifflin/comments/6x62mz/just_michael_pouring_sugar_into_a_diet_coke/'};
ogs(options, function (err, results) {
    console.log('err:', err); // This is returns true or false. True if there was a error. The error it self is inside the results object.
    console.log('results:', results);
});```
I just tried the above code, and I got OG information back, could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

`var ogs = require('open-graph-scraper');
var options = {'url': 'https://www.reddit.com/r/DunderMifflin/comments/6x62mz/just_michael_pouring_sugar_into_a_diet_coke/',timeout:5000};
ogs(options, function (err, results) {
    console.log('err:', err); // This is returns true or false. True if there was a error. The error it self is inside the results object.
    console.log('results:', results);
});`

yields:

`results: { data:
   { ogSiteName: 'reddit',
     ogDescription: '13852 points and 297 comments so far on reddit',
     ogTitle: 'Just Michael pouring sugar into a Diet Coke • r/DunderMifflin',
     twitterSite: 'reddit',
     twitterCard: 'summary',
     twitterTitle: 'Just Michael pouring sugar into a Diet Coke • r/DunderMifflin',
     ogImage:
      { url: 'https://i.redditmedia.com/sxdktAlu5OzAhSED5l75lOCNH1B7K1tmgZNxgoBj2oo.jpg?w=320&s=f529abd27b72fe5a6a246cc6505fb5a4',
        width: '320',
        height: null,
        type: null } },
  success: true }`

Sometimes redirects take a second, and it can be a good idea to increase the timeout in the request. This allows the library to get to the correct page before extracting og data. open-graph-scanner uses the request library underneath, which will keep following redirects until it gets to the main page. If that still isn't working, ensure you can access the page with a web browser.